# When can I address variables without using the "ptr" keyword?

Tags: assembly, x86, inline-assembly

So far, when addressing a variable or parameter in x86 inline assembly by its name, I wrote `dword ptr[varname]`, for example.
Recently I saw a piece of code that just used `[varname]` as an operand to address the variable.

So when do I have to use the `dword ptr` before the braces and when not?
In cases where I do not need it, is it optional or semantically different?

Comment: When the assembler can infer the size of the memory operand without it.

Comment: Similar to a C cast - specify the required operand size to prevent an assembler error when you are loading a register from a memory operand of a different size.

Comment: @RossRidge Then why is it not `ptr[varname]` oder `dword[varname]`? I think the `ptr` is not actually part of the datatype, right?

Comment: Conceptually its because its converting the value of `varname` to a pointer to DWORD. Syntactically because DWORD used to expand to the number 4 (its length) and `4[varname]` means something else.

Comment: In NASM syntax, you *do* write `inc dword [label]`.  The `ptr` is only required (and only accepted) in MASM syntax (including the style used by gcc with `-masm=intel`).  See also the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for more links to assembler manuals and tons of other stuff.  (Thanks @Ross for pointing out that it's not just syntactical filler / fluff.)

Comment: x86 inline assembly for which compiler? If GCC or similar, then mention that. There are other compilers (even non-C, non-C++, e.g. Delphi) that have inline assemblers, and they don't all use the same syntax.

Comment: @PeterCordes: `ptr` is also allowed (and sometimes required) in Delphi's inline assembler. The question does not mention which compiler is being used. This assembler does, BTW, not use an external assembler, it is part of the language.